# How do I tell Rust that something implements a trait?

Tags: rust, annotations, traits, generic-programming

I'm trying to write a generic function that returns an iterator.

```
fn one_to_ten<T: Add>() -> std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> {
    (1..5).chain(5..=10)
}
```

It's generic because it needs to work for `u8` through `u128`, and preferably also `i8` through `i128`, for the following code:

```
let mut sum: u64 = 0;
for x in one_to_ten() {
    sum += x;
}
```

Unfortunately, Rust complains:

> = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> + 'static)`
>   error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = _>` cannot be known at compilation time

and

> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>   expected trait std::iter::Iterator, found struct `std::iter::Chain`

I'm out of my depth here. Rust seems to think I'm trying to implement a dynamically dispatched function, when I'm trying to implement a generic one instead. (And, for some reason, my chained iterator isn't accepted as an iterator – my guess is that I'm specifying a type instead of a trait, but `std::iter::Iterator` is a trait, not a type.)

What should my code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traits are unsized so you cannot return a value of trait type. Instead you must return a value of a type that implements that trait:

```rust
fn one_to_ten<T: Add>() -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> {
    (1..5).chain(5..=10)
}
```

Unfortunately that brings another issue, that the `(1..5)` code builds a range of integers, not of `T`. You can fix that with a custom trait, as the `std::iter::Step` is still unstable.

Something like [this (playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3bc27fd8dad89341cdc3560bc80bc67e):

```rust
pub trait MyRange: Sized {
    type Iter: std::iter::Iterator<Item = Self>;
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> Self::Iter;
    fn new_incl(a: i32, b: i32) -> Self::Iter {
        Self::new(a, b + 1)
    }
}

impl MyRange for i8 {
    type Iter = std::ops::Range<Self>;
    fn new(a: i32, b: i32) -> Self::Iter {
        (a as i8 .. b as i8) //check overflow?
    }
}

pub fn one_to_ten<T: Add + MyRange>() -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> {
    T::new(1, 5).chain(T::new_incl(5, 10))
}
```

And then implement the `MyRange` trait for every integer type you need.